# This and closures in javascript (working in paper.js)

Tags: javascript, closures, this, paperjs

I'm still wrapping my head around closures.

I'm working on a project using `Paper.js` and `paperscript`.  I am trying to create line segments with a distance metric that stays in the center of the segment as it is moved.

Instead of simply writing code to move the center and the line separately (which would be pretty simple), I've been seeing whether it could be possible to move the line and have the center follow.

This is proving difficult.  There may be several problems with it, but right now `this` is my current bugaboo.  They way I have it set up now, `this` refers to the global object when the function is called, which of course not what I want.  But I can't figure out how to create what I want, which is of course a baked-in reference from the 'weight' element to the 'line' element.

How do I do this correctly?

```
edge = new Group({
    children: [
        new Path.Line({
            from: gn.position,
            to: event.point,
            strokeColor: 'maroon',
            name: 'line'
        }),
        new PointText(function (){
            return {
                position: function () {
                    return this.previousSibling.position;
                }(),
                content: function () {
                    return this.previousSibling.length.toString();
                }(),
                name: 'weight'
            }
        }())
    ]
});
```

Comment: The value of *this* has nothing to do with closures, it's always resolved in the current execution context and is set by how you call the function, or *bind*.

Comment: Can you explain more?  I'm trying to create a situation where the `this` gets somehow permanently coded into the functions in the object, and I thought a closure might help with doing that.  What's my best strategy?

Comment: "*this refers to the global scope when the function is called*" Which function? And I think you mean *global object*, you can't reference scope in any way.

Comment: you could call bind() in each function you want to create a definitive relation between that function and a `this` context, but I guess you'd better   change the wat your code is written.

Comment: @RobG - the functions supposed to return the new position and content of the PointText object.  `this` doesn't mean the PointText object... I want it to refer to its own previous sibling.

Comment: @Werlang...  Can you explain a little more how I should change the way the code is written?

Comment: @RobG and yes, you're right, of course, global object.  Editing the question.

Comment: You have: `position: function () {return this.previousSibling.position;}()`, which is an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE), its *this* is not set to any value in the call so it defaults to the global object. You can't set the IIFE's *this* to the new *PointText* object as it doesn't exist at the time the IIFE is executed. See Werlang's answer.

Answer (score 2):

In order to give a better structure, and bind a `this` reference, you can start defining a constructor function:

```
function PointTextContent(name) {
  this.position = function () {
    return this.previousSibling.position;
  }.bind(this);
  this.content = function () {
    return this.previousSibling.length.toString();
  }.bind(this);
  this.name = name;

  PointText.call(this, this);
}

PointTextContent.prototype = PointText;
```

Then change your code to instantiate your new object.

```
edge = new Group({
    children: [
        new Path.Line({
            from: gn.position,
            to: event.point,
            strokeColor: 'maroon',
            name: 'line'
        }),
        new PointTextContent('weight')
    ]
});
```

NOTE: I changed `position` and `content` to become functions, I see they were immediately invoked in your original code.

Comment: I think this is close, but *this* within *position* will reference the *PointTextContent* instance, whereas I think the OP wants it to reference the *PointText* instance. I don't see how that can be done in the call, since *this* needs to reference an object that doesn't exist yet. But I might be wrong about that…

Comment: @RobG you're right. i changed my mind during writing this code. perhaps subclassing PointText...

Comment: Okay, so I dropped this into my script, and I'm getting my personal favorite Javascript error `undefined is not a function` on `PointText.call(this, this)`.

Perhaps worth mentioning that `PointText` is a paperjs object.  Can't really imagine why that should matter... but seems like we can't call it?

Comment: Though I'm not sure about that... the full stack trace goes into the TextItem class (can I say "class" in Javascript?) which PointText inherits from.

I also don't completely understand what PointText.call(this,this) is supposed to do here.  Wouldn't that create a PointText object _within_ PointTextContent?

Comment: I believe the error is inside PointText(). Try stepping into.

Comment: Yes, I think it has to do with what PointText expects as its arguments for the constructor. 

I should have mentioned before that I don't really understand the second `this` in `PointText.call(this,this)`.  I think if I do it will be a lot easier... PointText expects a single argument that is an object - this is probably what is going wrong.

Comment: .call() invokes original function and sets a specific context during its execution. Its a temporal bind(). The first this is the context (act on this object), the second is actual argument to PointText(). I suggest researching around this subject.

Comment: I'm afraid I am giving up at the moment... The paperjs constructors are complicated and nested and I can't figure out how to make them happy. It's only a few lines to manage moving this thing separately. When I'm more of a ninja programmer I'll figure out how to do it the "proper" way. Very good primer on using `this`... but the paperjs objects may be a special case.